# Why would the XSLT to update Web.Config partly fail?

Tags: xslt, web-config, umbraco

I have an XSLT file that is used to write to my Web.Config as part of a build process for Umbraco. Writing things such as the "umbracoConfigurationStatus" value works fine, as does writing a new profile membership section.

However the part that tries to update or create a UmbracoMembershipProvider section is causing me all sorts of grief. It won't update or write. What am I missing?

Here's the bulk of the XSLT file:

```
  <xsl:template match="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='umbracoConfigurationStatus']/@value">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">4.7.1.1</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/configuration/system.web">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="copy-children" />
            <xsl:element name="profile">
                <xsl:attribute name="defaultProvider">
                    <xsl:text>UmbracoMemberProfileProvider</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="enabled">
                    <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="inherits">
                    <xsl:text>umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member.MemberProfile</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="providers">
                    <xsl:element name="clear" />
                    <xsl:element name="add">
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                            <xsl:text>UmbracoMemberProfileProvider</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="type">
                            <xsl:text>umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoProfileProvider, umbraco.providers</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="properties">
                    <xsl:element name="clear" />
                    <xsl:element name="add">
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                            <xsl:text>auth_guid</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="allowAnonymous">
                            <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="provider">
                            <xsl:text>UmbracoMemberProfileProvider</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="type">
                            <xsl:text>System.String</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="add">
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                            <xsl:text>firstName</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="allowAnonymous">
                            <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="provider">
                            <xsl:text>UmbracoMemberProfileProvider</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="type">
                            <xsl:text>System.String</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="add">
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                            <xsl:text>lastName</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="allowAnonymous">
                            <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="provider">
                            <xsl:text>UmbracoMemberProfileProvider</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="type">
                            <xsl:text>System.String</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="copy-children">
        <xsl:copy-of select="./*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/configuration/system.web/membership/providers">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="copy-children" />
            <xsl:element name="add">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">
                    <xsl:text>UmbracoMembershipProvider</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="type">
                    <xsl:text>umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="enablePasswordRetrieval">
                    <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="enablePasswordReset">
                    <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="requiresQuestionAndAnswer">
                    <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="defaultMemberTypeAlias">
                    <xsl:text>SiteMember</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="umbracoApprovePropertyTypeAlias">
                    <xsl:text>isApproved</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="umbracoLockPropertyTypeAlias">
                    <xsl:text>isLocked</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="passwordFormat">
                    <xsl:text>Hashed</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Default templates to match anything else -->
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

The state I'm trying to get to is:

```
<add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="SiteMember" umbracoApprovePropertyTypeAlias="isApproved" umbracoLockPropertyTypeAlias="isLocked" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this because you have a template to match the **configuration/system.web** element...

```
<xsl:template match="/configuration/system.web">
```

... but within this, you do not tell the XSLT processor to continue matching any templates against the descendants. This means, the template for **configuration/system.web/membership/providers** won't be matched.

You do call the named template **copy-children** though, but all this does is an **xsl:copy-of** which will copy the children nodes exactly, but won't match any templates that may exist for them.

Change the **copy-children** template to the following, and see how you get on.

```
<xsl:template name="copy-children">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

As a side note, there is no real need to use **xsl:element** and **xsl:attribute** to create elements and attributes if you are always using fixed names. For example

```
<xsl:element name="add">
   <xsl:attribute name="name">
      <xsl:text>UmbracoMembershipProvider</xsl:text>
   </xsl:attribute>
<xsl:element>
```

This could simply be replaced with the following, which could cut down the size of your XSLT

```
<add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" />
```

EDIT: As well as changing the **copy-children** template as described above, another issue you may have is with this matching template.

```
<xsl:template match="/configuration/system.web/membership">
   <xsl:attribute name="MyAttrTest">the test value</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Here you are matching an element, but replacing it with an attribute. This is fine providing (as described in the error message) you have not added text or child elements previously. I suspect you should be doing this instead....

```
<xsl:template match="/configuration/system.web/membership">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="MyAttrTest">the test value</xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This will add create a copy of the **membership** element and add an attribute to it.

You should double-check all instances of where this may be occurring in your XSLT.

Comment: Good-looking solution, but still hasn't worked. What could be blocking this line?

Comment: I've added the full file here: http://pastebin.com/juKagtxv. Interestingly, if I remove the section that begins with     `<xsl:template match="/configuration/system.web">`, the update succeeds, but only to a point, returning an error: "Attribute and namespace nodes cannot be added to the parent element after a text, comment, pi, or sub-element node has already been added."

Comment: Any chance of seeing the web.config file too (with any sensitive information replaced by meaningless text, of course)?

Comment: I've spotted another potential issue, which I have added to my answer.